# Bitlocker not accepting pin but goes through after tapping enter a few times

Tags: windows, bitlocker, lenovo

This is one of the strangest errors I've run into.

We've recently gotten a batch of Lenovo Legions Y7000 1060's and they work great apart from one of them which doesn't accept its bitlocker pin, bootloops after sitting at the bitlocker screen for a few seconds, and this bootloop doesn't let you enter in the recovery key because it interrupts the recovery process.

BUT

What I can do is enter the pin, get the "Error incorrect pin" and tap enter quickly twice more and it will allow me through the unlock process.

I've removed and readded bitlocker to the drive, confirmed that the pin is correct, and applied all needed firmware updates to the device - but the issue persists. Has anyone else run into this before?

Update 1:

I've gone through and compared the policy with

```
manage-bde -status
```

against working machines as well as used

```
bcdedit /enum
```

and it all returns the same values, meaning there is not a difference in how they are deployed.

Comment: Possibly related: https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/ADV180028

Comment: We're using software encryption, I wish it was applicable.